# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: django, postgresql, load-testing, locust

I am running a Django app on Django's development server with PostgreSQL as the backend database. I got this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

when I was doing a load testing using Locust. My Locust script runs the test with 100 concurrent clients:

```
env.runner.start(100, spawn_rate=100, wait=True)
```

I have seen several answers on SO, such as:

1. [Getting OperationalError: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already using psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519296/getting-operationalerror-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already-using-psycopg2)
2. [Getting "FATAL: sorry, too many clients already" when the max_connections number is not reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824995/getting-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already-when-the-max-connections-number)
3. [Django+Postgres FATAL: sorry, too many clients already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843123/djangopostgres-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already)

From those threads, I think I understand the cause of the error, but I am still very confused. How does it scale in real life if PostgreSQL cannot handle even 100 concurrent clients?
Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am using a development server? Will it help if I use Gunicorn? If some connection clean-up is needed, is it something that I should implement in the Locust script? I am quite new in this area, so I apologize if the answers to those questions are obvious.

Comment: Did you manage to find out what's wrong? experienced the same as you